# Datatables: Filter results on page load

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to filter JQuery Datatable results from a page load?

Load a URL: https://example.com/table.php?search=test

Then the page uses PHP to $GET_['search'] term and then injects that search term into the Datatables search field and filtering the results by 'test'. If the user removes the search term 'test' then then page loads all the original results.

By the way, the data is static table data on page load, not ajax/server-side data.

Thanks

Comment: Datatables offers Filtering for the table: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html If you mean something else, please post a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: for example: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html?search=Tokyo then when the page loads, 'Tokyo' is in the search field thereby filtering the results on page load

Comment: You can do this with the `search()`, see more: https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `search` option.

https://datatables.net/reference/option/search

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/e971x2jy/5/

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "search": {
      "search": "Tokyo"
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow that is exactly what I was looking for but could not find it in the docs or a Google search. Thanks!